# why space comes after body tag in first line in inspect element?

Tags: php, html, css, document-body

```
<html>
  <head>
     <title>PHP</title>
   </head>
        <body>
        <?php 
                echo 'hello';
        ?>
        </body>
 </html>
```

**update:**

1. If i used `<fieldset>` tag in above script problem become solved.

[**PHPFIDDLE**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/0j8y-2grm) -- *RUN THE CODE AND CHECK IN INSPECT ELEMENT*

[image]

Comment: `trim()` will remove these spaces. It sounds like you're padding it afterwards, or outputting a space somewhere else. Can you please post the output of `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` and `var_dump(urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))`?

Comment: You're looking at the output in an html browser?

Comment: COuld you show us more of your code? Because the code example should not behave like you described.

Comment: post code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: trim "works" : http://codepad.org/CO8BuzjB

Comment: There might be a whitespace before and after the php tags maybe?

Comment: don't use the close tag at the end of file. don't use `echo` for debugging, there's `var_dump` and `print_r` (or encapsulate them in your own debugging function).

Comment: @Brewal yes its works when we take as `string`. but not working when i am testing on my local and production server.

Comment: @h2ooooooo dude i am not using any other code. only used above code.

Comment: @Prashant We still need more info from you. Use the `var_dump` methods I've mentioned. You most likely have your whitespace somewhere else (maybe after the ending PHP tag).

Comment: @VolkerK yes i looking at the output in an html browser

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but too long for a comment:
Please try again with

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
function printit($s) {
    echo '<fieldset>',
        htmlspecialchars(var_export($s)),
        '<br />';
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($s); $i++) {
        printf('%02X ', ord($s[$i]));
    }
    echo '</fieldset>';
}

printit($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
printit(trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])); 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

and add the output to your question.

Comment: `'/clothing/test.php'
2F 49 64 69 6F 74 68 65 6F 72 79 2F 74 65 73 74 32 2E 70 68 70
'/clothing/test.php'
2F 49 64 69 6F 74 68 65 6F 72 79 2F 74 65 73 74 32 2E 70 68 70` in two square box

Comment: Ok, so there are no whitespaces - neither before nor after the string.

Comment: yes. there is no whitespace. can u explain me what is problem and what u had done? –  Prashant 11 mins ago

Comment: The script does nothing to those two strings. It only shows rather unambiguously what the contents of the strings is. So, if you still have those whitespaces in your script it's not trim's fault; they must originate from something else.

Comment: if i inserted in between fieldset tag then no space for both like that `echo '<fieldset>';
print_r($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
 echo '</fieldset>';`

Comment: Then you've put the output somewhere in your html document where whitespaces (including line breaks) do matter.